# How can I change icon inside button on hover using chakra-ui and vanilla-extract?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui, vanilla-extract

- I am using nextjs13, chakra-ui, and vanilla-extract

Does anyone know how to change icon and text inside button on hover, using chakra-ui and vanilla-extract?

I have a button like this:

```
<Button >
 <svg width="16" height="18">
  <use xlinkHref={path/to/iconA}></use>
 </svg>
{!isFollowing ? <span>follow</span> : <span>following</span>}
</Button>
```

I want to show 'follow' button with icon A if logged in user is not following the user.
I want to show "following" with icon A if logged in user is following the user.

When I hover the button(and logged in user is currently following the user),
I want to change button text: from "following" to "unfollow" with red text color and icon: from iconA to iconB.

I could change the text color by adding css to span:
`<span className={textCss}>following</span>`

```
const textCss = style({
":hover":{
color:"red"
}})
```

but not sure how to change the text and icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved issue by adding 'isHover' as state variable.

```
const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(false);

<Button onMouseEnter={() => setIsHover(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setIsHover(false)}>
 <svg width="16" height="18">
  <use xlinkHref={ !isFollowing && isHover? path/to/iconB: path/to/iconA}> 
  </use>
 </svg>
 {!isFollowing ? <span>follow</span> : <span>following</span>}
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following

```
import * as styles from './styles.css'
<Button className={styles.button}>
 <svg width="16" height="18">
  <use xlinkHref={isFollowing ? 'path/to/iconA' : 'path/to/iconAB'}></use>
 </svg>
<span className={styles.buttonText}>{isFollowing ? 'unfollow' : 'follow'}</span>
</Button>
```

and for your vanilla extract css file you could do something like this

```
export const button = style({})
export const buttonText = style({
    selectors: {
        `${button}:hover &`: { 
             color: 'red'
         }
     }
})
```

Vanilla extract provide some good documentation [that can be found here](https://vanilla-extract.style/documentation/styling/#complex-selectors).

Comment: thanks for the answer. What I want to achieve is to show iconB only when isFollowing=true && when I hover the button. do you have any idea? @jnbjarni

Comment: Then you need to store in state variable information about the hover state of the button. `const [hover, setHover] = useState(false)` and then on your button component you need to add the two methods that track if the user is hovering `<Button onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)} onMouseOver={() => setHover(true)}>...</Button />`, and finally you add the check on the icon `<use xlinkHref={isFollowing && hover ? 'path/to/iconB' : 'path/to/iconA'}></use>`. Should note that this is just rough pseudo code but should aim you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to change the color of the existing icon, you can change the SVG file to have `fill="curentColor"` throughout that file, and then using
`svg:hover { fill: red; }` should work for you.